# Null check operator used on a null value when submitting a form

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to send form data to an API after pressing the submit button for a form but each time I'm getting an error "Null check operator used on a null value" and does not send the data. Below is my code.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
//import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:keilvog/Screens/6kg_cylinder_screen.dart';
import 'package:keilvog/Widget/edit_image.dart';
import 'package:keilvog/Widget/header.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:keilvog/Widget/validators.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
Future<dynamic> UploadData(
    {String? brand, 
    String? capacity, 
    String? amount, 
    //File? image
    }) async {
  final SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final String? myJWT = preferences.getString('jwt');
  Map<String, dynamic> token = jsonDecode(myJWT!);
  Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    'brand': brand,
    'capacity': capacity,
    'amount': int.parse(amount!),
    // 'image':
    //     'data:image/png;base64,' + base64Encode(image!.readAsBytesSync()),
  };
  var url = Uri.parse('https://kelivog.com/sell/cylinder');

  var myRequest = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);

  // var stream = http.ByteStream((image!.openRead()));

  // var length = await image.length();

  myRequest.headers.addAll(
      {"Authorization": token['token'], "Content-Type": "application/json"});

  // var multipartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
  //     'photo', image.path); 
  //myRequest.files.add(multipartFile);
  http.StreamedResponse response = await myRequest.send();
  final responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(response.statusCode);
  }
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(responseString);
  }

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(jsonEncode(body));
    }

    final myResponse = await http.Client().get(
      Uri.parse('https://kelivog.com/sell/cylinder'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Authorization': token['token']
      },
    );

    if (myResponse.statusCode == 200) {
      final myData = json.decode(myResponse.body);
      myData['data'].length == 0
          ? await http.Client()
              .post(
                Uri.parse('https://kelivog.com/sell/61ed7fa0ce1fd097aa002a3d'),
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                  'Authorization': token['token']
                },
                body: jsonEncode(body),
              )
              .then((value) => {
                    if (value.statusCode == 200)

                      // ignore: avoid_print
                      {
                        print("POST Successful"),

                        // ignore: avoid_print
                        print(jsonEncode(body))
                      }
                    else
                      // ignore: avoid_print
                      {print("FAILED")}
                  })
          : await http.Client()
              .put(
                Uri.parse('https://kelivog.com/sell/61ed7fa0ce1fd097aa002a3d'),
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                  'Authorization': token['token']
                },
                body: jsonEncode(body),
              )
              .then((value) => {
                    if (value.statusCode == 200)
                      {
                        // ignore: avoid_print
                        print("PUT Successful"),
                        // ignore: avoid_print
                        print(jsonEncode(body)),
                      }
                    else
                      // ignore: avoid_print
                      {print("FAILED")}
                  });

      return myResponse.statusCode;
    } else {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(myResponse.statusCode);
      }
      throw Exception('Failed to update Profile.' '${myResponse.body}');
    }
  } else {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("ERROR");
    }
  }
}

class SellDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const SellDetails({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SellDetails> createState() => _SellDetailsState();
}

class _SellDetailsState extends State<SellDetails> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final brandController = TextEditingController();
  final capacityController = TextEditingController();
  final amountController = TextEditingController();
  //File? image;
  bool isLoading = false;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("images/background.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover)
              ),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              header(),
              SizedBox(height: 20.h),
              //const EditImage(),

               Container(
                width: 190.w,
                height: 125.h,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("images/others.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
              ),

              ),



              SizedBox(height: 30.h),
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                //autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                child: Container(
                  width: 350.w,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.r)),
                    image: const DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("images/background.jpg"),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    ),
                    boxShadow: const [
                      BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, spreadRadius: 2),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 12.h, horizontal: 16.w),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text("BRAND",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.sp,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  )),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 1.w),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                width: 90.w,
                                height: 40.h,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.yellow[600],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    //textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                                    validator: brandValidator,
                                    controller: brandController,
                                    showCursor: false,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      height: 2.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 1.0, bottom: 100.0, left: 8.0),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(15.0)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      //const Divider(indent: 15, endIndent: 15, thickness: 2),

                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 12.h, horizontal: 16.w),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text("CAPACITY",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.sp,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  )),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 1.w),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                width: 90.w,
                                height: 40.h,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.yellow[600],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    validator: capacityValidator,
                                    controller: capacityController,
                                    showCursor: false,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      height: 2.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 1.0, bottom: 100.0, left: 8.0),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(15.0)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 12.h, horizontal: 16.w),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text("AMOUNT",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.sp,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  )),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 1.w),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                width: 90.w,
                                height: 40.h,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.yellow[600],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    validator: amountValidator,
                                    controller: amountController,
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                    showCursor: false,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      height: 2.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 1.0, bottom: 100.0, left: 8.0),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(15.0)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                      
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 40.h),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    if (kDebugMode) {
                      print('Imageeee');
                    }

                    //if (image != null) {
                      await UploadData(
                        //image: image,
                        brand: brandController.text,
                        capacity: capacityController.text,
                        amount: amountController.text,
                        // serviceFee: double.parse(serviceFeeController.text),
                        // takeHome: double.parse(takeHomeController.text),
                      );
                    // }
                    //  else {
                    //   // ignore: avoid_print
                    //   print('You have not added an image');
                    // }
                    if (isLoading) {
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  const SixCylindersListsScreen(
                                    item: '',
                                    id: '',
                                    title: '',
                                  )));
                    } else {
                      throw Exception('Failed to upload details.');
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  'UPLOAD',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.yellow[600],
                    fontSize: 22.sp,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  elevation: 5,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.r),
                  ),
                  fixedSize: Size(150.w, 50.h),
                  primary: const Color(0xff261005),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have commented out some parts of the code while trying to debug but still getting the same error. The error points to the line with **await UploadData**

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    if (kDebugMode) {
                      print('Imageeee');
                    }
                   
               //////////THE ERROR POINTS HERE////////
                      await UploadData(
                        
                        brand: brandController.text,
                        capacity: capacityController.text,
                        amount: amountController.text,
                      );
```

Comment: This means one of your data is empty. This error points out that you are trying to check if value is null when its already null

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when a bang (!) operator is used on a nullable instance that hasn't been initialized. Check the logs which line on your code the error is thrown.

To solve this issue, you can initialize a default value for the variable

```dart
String foo = 'defaultValue';

if(newValue != null){
  foo = newValue;
}

bar(foo);
```

...or set a default fallback value for the nullable variable if the value is null with (??).

```dart
String? foo;

bar(foo?.getValue() ?? 'defaultValue');
```